# Sorting copied variable change the value of original variable

Tags: javascript

I have a problems that driving me nuts.

I need 2 arrays One to handle and other to use as reference. one gives the number and de second search position in the array.

This is the sample of my code:

```
var var1 = [37, 82, 4, 67, 23, 15];
var var2 = [];
function avaliador(a){
    var2 = var1;
    var2.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
    console.log(var1);
    console.log(var2);
    //... function continues
}
```

My objective is have:

```
    console.log(var1); // [37, 82, 4, 67, 23, 15];
    console.log(var2); // [4, 15, 23, 37, 67, 82];
```

And this is what i got:

```
    console.log(var1); // [4, 15, 23, 37, 67, 82];
    console.log(var2); // [4, 15, 23, 37, 67, 82];
```

I missing something in my logic?

Comment: var1 and var2 are both referencing the same array. You need to create a copy of the array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`var2` is a reference to `var1`; they are the same array.

You need to clone `var1` when assigning to `var2`. This can be done with `slice`:

```js
var1 = [37, 82, 4, 67, 23, 15];

function avaliador(a){
    var2 = var1.slice();
    var2.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
    console.log(var1);
    console.log(var2);
    //... function continues
}

avaliador()
```

Comment: So a = b o just reference?
Always think when a use "=" i create a copy the variable/array and not just a reference.
I learn all by myself so i didnt know it

Thanks for help, it worked.
I will try reformulate all my logic :)